# How to find final object on category of $G$-sets?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

This question was asked in my assignment on Commutative Algebra and I was not able to make any significant progress on it.

> Question: Let $G$ be a group. A $G$-set is a set $S$ together with a left action of $G$ on $S$, that is, a map $G \times S \to S$, $(g,s) \mapsto gs$ satisfying $1s = s$ and $g(hs) = (gh)s$ for all $g,h \in G$
> and $s\in S$. A morphism of $G$-sets is a map $f:S \to T$ satisfying
> $f(gs) = gf(s) $for every $s \in S$ and $g \in G$. The category of $G$-sets is
> denoted $G_{\mathrm{Set}}$. What are the final objects of $G_{\mathrm{Set}}$?

An object $X$ is called final if for every $Y\in \mathrm{Obj}(C)$ there exists a unique morphism $Y\to X$.

Attempt: I understand the definition of final object but how to prove what is required ? What should I choose $Y$? I think it will be $G$. I think $X$ is any set which is a subset of $G$. Let $f$ and $p$ be 2 such morphisms. Then $f(gs)=p(gs) \implies gf(s)- gp(s)=0 \implies f(s) -p(s)=0$ for all $s \in S$.

But how to show that $f $ equals to $p$ for all values in its domain?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you should choose $Y$? By the way, I can give you the following suggestion: the final object of a category is unique up to unique isomorphism. This should suggest you that the final object that you are looking for should be a very easy object

Comment: Hint: consider the final object in Set, the category of sets and functions.

Comment: To get a big hint: the forgetful functor (underlying set functor) $G{-}Set \to Set$ is representable by the $G$-set $G$ with action being left multipication.  In other words, there's a natural isomorphism $U(S) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}_{G{-}Set}(G, S)$.  On the other hand, if $S$ is a final object, what do you know about $\operatorname{Hom}_{G{-}Set}(X, S)$ for general $X$?

Comment: Also, the question title asks about initial object, but the question body asks about final object.  Which one are you actually asking about?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: When you view the group $G$ as a category $BG$ with a single object $\ast$ and morphisms the elements of $G$, then the category of $G$-sets is isomorphic to the functor category $[BG,Set]$. This means you only have to find out how initial and terminal objects in functor categories look like.